# Adding jpeg textures to a .obj object

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials

I need help in figuring out how to add jpeg textures and materials to a .obj file, I'm just in the process of designing a kitchen and downloaded a few appliances to add to the project. The download consisted of a .obj and a .fbx file.
Also a .mtl and map file with a few jpeg texture images.

I can get to import the .obj and .fbx files but need help with adding the texture images to the model. I have tried looking online and YouTube to find out how to solve my problem but nothing really there to answer the question.

I am new to this kind of designing but have many years with using AutoCAD for my work. I can do all the actual designing no problem but its just this problem what's holding my project back. Would i have to use the node wrangler to add these textures to the model and how would i go about laying them out? Also would it be in UV editing or the shader option??

Hope i can get answers with this hold back. Currently using 2.92 version of blender.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F5M0ZuL-eg <- relevant tutorial. You probably won't need to edit the UVs yourself if you downloaded them.

Comment: Thank you for the link.Found it very informative.